# Convert to and from the factorial number system

Tags: code-golf, number, base-conversion

The [Factorial Number System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system), also called factoradic, is a mixed radix numeral system. The factorials determine the place value of a number.

In this system, the right most digit can be either 0 or 1, the second rightmost digit can be 0, 1 or 2, and so on. This means that an `n` digit factoradic number can have a maximum value of `(n + 1)!`.

For example, to convert the factoradic number `24201` to decimal you would do this:

```
2 * 5! = 240
4 * 4! = 96
2 * 3! = 12
0 * 2! = 0
1 * 1! = 1
240 + 96 + 12 + 0 + 1 = 349
```

Hence the factoradic number `24201` is `349` base `10`.

To convert a decimal number (with `349` as an example) into a factoradic number, you would do this:

Take the largest factorial less than the number. In this case it is `120`, or `5!`.

```
349 / 5! = 2 r 109
109 / 4! = 4 r 13
13 / 3! = 2 r 1
1 / 2! = 0 r 1
1 / 1! = 1 r 0
```

Hence `349` base `10` is the factoradic number `24201`.

Your challenge is to create the shortest program or function that converts an input number to the other base.

The input will be a string representation of a non-negative integer. A factoradic number will be preceded by a `!` (eg. `!24201`), while a decimal number will not be preceded by anything. You may assume that the maximum input will be `10! - 1` - `3628799` in decimal and `987654321` in factoradic. This means that letters will not appear in a factoradic input/output.

The program doesn't need to prepend a `!` to a factoradic output, and may output a string or an integer. The input may be in any reasonable format.

---

Test cases:

```
Input: 1234
Output: 141120

Input: 746
Output: 101010

Input: !54321
Output: 719

Input: !30311
Output: 381
```

Comment: Mentioned in this [XKCD comic](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/2835:_Factorial_Numbers) yesterday :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### APL, <strike>39</strike> 37 characters

```
{A B←(9⍴10)(⌽1+⍳9)⌽⍨'!'∊⍵⋄A⊥B⊤⍎⍵~'!'}
```

Examples:

```
      {A B←(9⍴10)(⌽1+⍳9)⌽⍨'!'∊⍵⋄A⊥B⊤⍎⍵~'!'}'1234'
141120
      {A B←(9⍴10)(⌽1+⍳9)⌽⍨'!'∊⍵⋄A⊥B⊤⍎⍵~'!'}'!54321'
719
```

Comment: I think you can replace `⍴⍵∩'!'` with `'!'∊⍵` to save a character.

Comment: @Volatility Yes you can. I also found another one.

Comment: IMO having the word "pwn" in your script is well worth the extra character.

Comment: I agree with ejrb. Would you break this down please?

Comment: Replace `~'!'` with `∩⎕D` to save a character.

Answer (score 10):

### Python 2.7 (<s>163</s> <s>157</s> 152)

```
i=raw_input()
exec("b='';a=362880;j=int(i);x=9;"+'b+=`j//a`;j%=a;a/=x;x-=1;'*9,"a=x=1;b=0;"+'b+=a*int(i[-x]);x+=1;a*=x;'*~-len(i))['!'in i]
print int(b)
```

More readable version:

```
i=raw_input()
if'!'in i:a=x=1;b=0;c='b+=a*int(i[-x]);x+=1;a*=x;'*~-len(i)
else:b='';a=362880;j=int(i);x=9;c='b+=`j//a`;j%=a;a/=x;x-=1;'*9
exec c;print int(b)
```

Breakdown:

```
Factoradic -> Decimal, when i is in the form !(number)
a=1   #Factorial value (multiplied every iteration)
x=1   #Index value
b=0   #Output
iterate ~-len(i) times:    #PSEUDOCODE! bitwisenot(a) = ~a = -a-1
    b+=a*int(i[-x])        #add the value of the xth last character in the factoradic #
    x+=1                   #Increment x
    a*=x                   #Set a to x!, (x-1)! * x = x!

Decimal -> Factoradic
b=''                       #Output
a=362880                   #Factorial value, set to 9! here
j=int(i)                   #Integer value of the input
x=9                        #Index value
iterate 9 times:           #PSEUDOCODE! This block is in an exec() loop
    b+=`j/a`               #Add floor(j/a) to b
    j%=a                   #Take out all multiples of a in j
    a/=x                   #Set a to (x-1)!, x! / x = (x-1)!
    x-=1                   #Decrement x
```

Comment: Nice solution. I think you can replace `'!'==i[0]` with `'!'in i`, and can use `a=x=1`. Also, you don't need brackets around the exec statement.

Comment: You could also replace `(len(i)-1)` with `~-len(i)`.

Comment: @Volatility, grc: Thanks! I should learn my bitwise operators :)

Comment: Nice answer, I took the liberty of trying to replace the if statement with `(a,b)['!'in i]` and managed to shave off 6 characters.  It's not as readable as it was though... [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/ruu5k6m8)

Comment: @erjb: Thanks for the suggestion! I used a 2-tuple with the code as a string in-line with the exec function, which saves two more characters :)

Answer (score 9):

### GolfScript (<strike>48 44</strike> 43 chars)

```
.~\{1{):?\.?%\?/@}9*{*+}+9*}:^{:N,{^N=}?}if
```

This is a self-contained program. The factoriadic => decimal conversion is quite slow, because it does a search using the decimal => factoriadic conversion rather than a direct base conversion.

The input format allows for a very short mode switch: `.~` copies the input string and evaluates it, so if the input is just a number we end up with e.g. `"1234" 1234` on the stack, and if it starts with `!` (logical not, with any non-empty string being truthy) we end up with e.g. `0 30311` on the stack. Then the value at the bottom of the stack is truthy for decimal => factoriadic and falsy for factoriadic => decimal.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP <7.1 <s>178 171 170 168 164 155 147 144 138 126</s> 123 bytes

```php
for($b=$j=1,$i=strlen($x=$argn);+$x?$b<=$x:--$i;$b*=++$j)$r+=$x[$i]*$b;if(+$x)for(;$j>1;$x%=$b)$r.=$x/($b/=$j--)|0;echo+$r;
```

Run as pipe with `-r` or [test it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e4764cc460fd438404d1959e1d3a674597941463).

- no extension required
- no <s>sub</s> function needed: the factorial base is being reused (incresed/decreased in the loops)
- pure integer and string arithmetics, should even work in php 3 (and still works in php 7):
- <s>decimal 0 returns empty string instead of `0`.</s> (both other PHP answers do too.) <s>If that is unacceptable, add +5 for the extra case.</s>

**ungolfed:**

```php
// two loops in one: compute the decimal number from a factorial
// or find the first factorial larger than a decimal $x
// the latter inits $r with '0': $i=strlen -> $x[$i]=='' -> (int)$x[$i]==$x[$i]*$b==0
// $b is the current digit´s base; $j is the bases´ latest factor
for($b=$j=1,$i=strlen($x=$argn);+$x?$b<=$x:--$i;$b*=++$j)
    $r+=$x[$i]*$b;
// and now for dec->fact ...
if(+$x)
    for(;$j>1;$x%=$b)
        // both $b and $j are one step too far in the first iteration;
        // -> decrement must precede the actual loop body
        // -> can be merged into the digit calculation -> all braces golfed
        $r.=$x/($b/=$j--)|0;
        // now: go on with the remainder (see loop head)
echo+$r; // final type cast removes leading zeros (from the first loop)
    // and fixes the '0' result (no operations at all on that input!)
```

**abandoned golfing ideas:**

- `$b<=$x` --> `$b<$x` (-1)
  would break pure decimal factorials (i.e. those that result in a factorial number with only one non-zero digit).
  JMPC´s solution suffers from that; HamZa´s does not.
- <s>`floor($x/$b)` -> `(int)($x/$b)`

  could be a bit faster, but type casting precedes division, so I need the parentheses and don´t gain a byte.</s> `$x/$b|0` does the trick
- <s>The loop in fact->dec is similar to the factorial-find in dec->fact. Same increment, body does not matter, but unfortunately different preset and different post condition. Dang; could have golfed -21 there.</s>
  YAY I found a solution. Took quite a bit of golfing, but chopped off another -4 (no: -9) *and* closed all bugs/loopholes.

Any more potential ... or am I done golfing?

Comment: @JörgHülsermann Thanks for the hint.

Comment: `+$r` instead of `$r|0` save one byte. Same for `if($x|0)`

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES 6) <s>139 137 122 113</s> 111

tried a different approach using some array magic; but I ended up at <s>174</s> 172 bytes with that:

```
f=x=>{if('!'==x[0]){a=x.split``.reverse();i=b=1;r=0;a.pop();a.map(d=>{r+=d*b;b*=++i})}else{t=[];for(i=b=1;b<=x;b*=++i){t.unshift(b)}r='';t.map(b=>{r+=x/b|0;x%=b})}return r}
```

So I just took my PHP code and translated it. Could remove all the `$`s and a few `;`, but the necessity to initialize vars ate up some of that benefit. Managed to golf both answers down a bit further, though.

**golfed**

```
f=x=>{for(r=0,b=j=1,i=x.length;x|0?b<=x:--i;b*=++j)r+=x[i]*b;if(x|0)for(r='';j>1;x%=b)r+=x/(b/=j--)|0;return r}
```

- first version returns '' for decimal 0; add +2 to fix
- second version requires string input
- both tested in Firefox, Edge and Opera

**ungolfed**

```
f=x=>
{
    for(r=0,b=j=1,i=x.length;x|0?b<=x:--i;b*=++j)
        r+=x[i]*b;
    if(x|0)
        for(r='';j>1;x%=b)
            r+=x/(b/=j--)|0;
    return r
}
```

**test suite**

```
<table id=out border=1><tr><th>dec</th><th>result<th>expected</th><th>ok?</th></tr></table>
<script>
    addR=(r,s)=>{var d=document.createElement('td');d.appendChild(document.createTextNode(s));r.appendChild(d)}
    test=(x,e)=>{var y=f(x),r=document.createElement('tr');addR(r,x);addR(r,y);addR(r,e);addR(r,e==y?'Y':'N');document.getElementById('out').appendChild(r)}
    samples={'349':'24201','1234':'141120','746':'101010','719':'54321','381':'30311','24':'1000','0':'0'};
    for(d in samples){test(d,samples[d]);test('!'+samples[d],d)}
</script>
```

Comment: ES5 doesn't have arrow notation IIRC. And if you're going to use ES6, then `.split('')` => `.split\`\``

Comment: @Zacharý Gna I should have noted what browser I tested it in ... probably Firefox or Opera. So ES 6?

Comment: Yeah, arrow notation is ES6.

Comment: Oh, that caught me off guard, I thought the code block at the top was your solution! Regardless, I don't think you need to say `f=`. Also, can `r+=(x/(b/=j--)|0)` be `r+=x/(b/=j--)|0`?

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 128 chars

This takes about half an hour to run, but it's small:

```
A=[`x`for x in xrange(10**9)if all(x/10**d%10<d+2 for d in range(9))]
i=raw_input()
print A.index(i[1:])if'!'in i else A[int(i)]
```

It builds a list of all <= 9 digit factoradic numbers in numeric order, then does a lookup or index to convert.

If you want to test, just replace `10**9` with `10**6` and restrict yourself to 6-digit variadic numbers.

I could technically save a character by using `range(10**9)` instead of `xrange(10**9)`.  Don't try this at home.

Comment: No space is needed between `d+2` and `for`

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>66</s> <s>65</s> 60 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Jo King*

```perl6
{/\!/??:1[.flip.chop.comb Z*[\*] 1..*]!![R~] .polymod(2..*)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcjNCgIhFAbQV/kuRMy4cLpqE0Q179AyR6I/KVCUaSVRr26zOYuTH1PoayxYeuzrpxupG4YtW@nDK8vbM82keMVJ2FE4sJTCEdnjz0HmFEpM90bN2X7r@1Lgm8W5hU8Tdqy0wcb0oLXRikF6pZkP9Q8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
ḊV€;0Æ¡µÆ!ṖḌƊ¬?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9qZWxsef//4biKVuKCrDsww4bCocK1w4Yh4bmW4biMxorCrD////8hNTQzMjE)

#### How it works

```
ḊV€;0Æ¡µÆ!ṖḌƊ¬?     Main link (monad). Input: integer or string
             ¬?  *) If the given input is a string, run 1); otherwise run 2)

ḊV€;0Æ¡  1) Factorial base -> integer
ḊV€         Remove "!" and map each char to number
   ;0       Append zero (this is needed to run the built-in correctly)
     Æ¡     Built-in conversion

Æ!ṖḌ  2) Integer -> factorial base
Æ!       Built-in conversion
  ṖḌ     Remove a zero at the end, and convert to decimal
```

#### Why `*)` works

`¬` is element-wise logical NOT. When given a single integer, it becomes a single zero, which is false. However, when given a string, each element (character) is turned to a zero, and the whole result is an array of zeroes which is true.

Zero as an integer is a special case. It goes through the "factorial -> integer" route, but it still gives zero which is correct.

## Without factorial base built-in, 25 bytes

```
⁵R!µ³%Ḋ:ṖUḌ
⁵R!ḋḊUV€ƊµÇ¬?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R49YgxUNbD21Wfbijy@rhzmmhD3f0cIFFH@7oBoqFhj1qWnOs69DWw@2H1tj///9f0dLC3MzUxNjIEAA)

#### How it works

```
⁵R!µ³%Ḋ:ṖUḌ  Aux. link (monad). Integer -> factorial base
⁵R!µ         Set (1..10)! as left argument
    ³%Ḋ:Ṗ    Compute each digit: (input % (2..10)!) // (1..9)!
         UḌ  Reverse and convert the digit array to decimal

⁵R!ḋḊUV€ƊµÇ¬?  Main link (monad).
         µÇ¬?  If the input is a string, apply the left chain;
               otherwise, apply the aux. link above
⁵R!            (1..10)!
   ḋ           Dot product with...
    ḊUV€Ɗ      Remove "!", reverse, map each character to digit
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica <strike>213 177</strike> 175

A factorial number is wrapped in `f[]`, whether it is input or output.

```
g@{n_,j_,r_}:=If[j==0,FromDigits@r,g@{q=QuotientRemainder[n,j!];q[[2]],j-1,Append[r,q[[1]]]}]
z@n_:=If[!IntegerQ@n, g[{n[[1]],9,{}}], f@Tr@(p=1;# (p++)!&/@Reverse@IntegerDigits@n)]
```

**Usage**

```
z[24201]
```

> f[349]

```
z[f[349]]
```

> 24201

*Conversion of factorial to decimal number*.
`QuotientRemainder[n,j!]` recursively acts on the digits of the factorial number from left to right, decrementing `j` at each step.   `QuotientRemainder[349, 5!]`, for instance, returns `{2, 109}` and so on.

*Conversion of decimal to factorial number*.
Moving right to left, the pure function, `# (p++)! &`, multiplies each digit,`#`, by the appropriate factorial.

Answer (score 1):

#### GolfScript, 69 characters

```
10,1>{1$*}*](.0=33={1>01/-1%0\{~@(@*@+}/\}{~\-1%{1$<},{1$1$/@@%}/}if;
```

Takes input from STDIN as usual and prints the result. [Online test](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyIhNTQzMjEiCgoxMCwxPnsxJCp9Kl0oLjA9MzM9ezE%2BMDEvLTElMFx7fkAoQCpAK30vXH17flwtMSV7MSQ8fSx7MSQxJC9AQCV9L31pZjs%3D&run=true).

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 221 chars

#### Code Golf

```
m v@(a:b)|a=='!'=(sum.zipWith(*)g.map(read.(:[])).reverse) b|True=(fst.until((<0).fst.snd)(\(s,(i,b))->(s*10+b`quot`f i,(i-1,b`rem`f i))).(\n->(0,((1+).last.takeWhile((n>=).f)$[1..], n))).read) v;g=scanl1(*)[1..];f=(g!!)
```

#### Usage

```
$ ghci factorial.hs
ghci> m "1234"
 141120
ghci> m "!54321"
 719
```

#### Ungolfed code

```
parse v@(a:b) | a == '!' = to b
              | otherwise = from v

to = sum . zipWith (*) factorials . map (read . (:[])) . reverse

from = fst . until finished next . boostrap . read
    where finished = ((<0) . fst . snd)
          next (s,(i,r)) = (s * 10 + r `quot` factorial i, (i-1 ,r `rem` factorial i))
          bootstrap n = (0, (lastFact n, n))
          lastFact n = (1+) . last . takeWhile ((n>=) . factorial) $ [1..]

factorials = scanl1 (*) [1..]

factorial = (factorials!!)
```

Comment: By far the most readable entry. Haskell FTW!

Answer (score 1):

## PHP <s>231</s> <s>214</s> 204

Newest Answer

```
function g($x){return $x?$x*g($x-1):1;}function f($x,$e){if($x[0]=="!"){for($t=1;$t<$c=strlen($x);$t++){$e+=$x[$t]*g($c-$t);}}else{while(g(++$p)<=$x);while(--$p){$e.=floor($x/g($p));$x%=g($p);}}return$e;}
```

Old Answer

```
 function f($n){if($n[0]=="!"){$n=str_split($n);$c=count($n);$f=$y=1;while($c-->1){$e+=($f*$n[$c]);$f*=++$y;}return$e;}else{for($i=$c=1;$i<$n;$i*=$c){$r[$c++]=$i;}foreach(array_reverse($r)as$t){$e.=floor($n/$t);$n=$n%$t;}return$e;}}
```

#### Example

```
echo f('349')."\n"
    .f('!24201')."\n"
    .f('1234')."\n"
    .f('746')."\n"
    .f('!54321')."\n"
    .f('!30311');
```

#### Output

```
24201
349
141120
101010
719
381
```

Comment: I count 212 for the new answer, not 214. $e needs no initialization (-6) and the `foreach(range())` can be replaced with a simple `for` loop (-9). I like the idea, though.

Comment: wrong result for pure factorials. `24` should return `1000` but returns `400`. fix: `g(++$p)<$x` --> `g(++$p)<=$x` (+1)

Comment: @Titus Thanks for both of your replies! I updated my answer. I appreciate you helping me improve my answer when yours seems far superior.

Comment: 1) I count 2 less than you, again: 204, not 206. Do You include a Windows line break in your byte count?
2) syntax error in `for` construct: `,` should be `;`
3) I have another 7 changes saving 20 bytes on that code. Want them?

Comment: D'oh! I fixed those when testing it, but forgot to copy it back. Well spotted. Also sure, I'll be grateful for any suggestions you provide.

Comment: Well, it´s actually only 5 changes, but one of them has three parts.
a) obsolete second argument for f() (-3)
b) obsolete blank in function g (-1)
c) obsolete braces in the true branch (-4)
d) swap true and false branches, invert the `if` condition, then use my sexy type cast to int (-6) This will not affect the decimal 0 result!
e) the remaining `for` construct can be rewritten with a very nice `while(++$t<$c=strlen($x))`: increment before body --> $t needs no initialization (-6)

Comment: sorry, d) gives only -5. forgot that you have to add a whitespace between `else` and `for`. but f) replace `floor()` with a sexy type cast (-5)

Answer (score 0):

## K, 102

```
"I"$,/$*:'|:'{{(x-y*g),g:_(x:*x)%y:*/1+!y}\[x,0n;|1+!{$[(x>(*/1+!y))&x<*/1+!y+1;y;.z.s[x;1+y]]}[x;0]]}
```

Could definitely be improved.

```
k)"I"$,/$*:'|:'{{,[;g]x-y*g:_(x:*x)%y:*/1+!y}\[(x;0n);|1+!{{$[(x>(*/1+!y))&x<*/1+!y+1;y;.z.s[x;1+y]]}[x;0]}x]} 349
24201
k)"I"$,/$*:'|:'{{,[;g]x-y*g:_(x:*x)%y:*/1+!y}\[(x;0n);|1+!{{$[(x>(*/1+!y))&x<*/1+!y+1;y;.z.s[x;1+y]]}[x;0]}x]} 746
101010
k)"I"$,/$*:'|:'{{,[;g]x-y*g:_(x:*x)%y:*/1+!y}\[(x;0n);|1+!{{$[(x>(*/1+!y))&x<*/1+!y+1;y;.z.s[x;1+y]]}[x;0]}x]} 1234
141120
```

Answer (score 0):

### VBA 225

Thanks to Titus for the help! Still looking to golf some more.

```
Sub a(b)
Set w=WorksheetFunction
e=Len(b)
If IsNumeric(b) Then
i=0
For d=0To 8
h=w.Fact(9-d)
g=b Mod h
If g<b+i Then
i=1
f=f &Int(b/h)
b=g
End If
Next
Else
For d=2To e
f=f+w.Fact(e-d-1)*Mid(b,d,1)
Next
End If
MsgBox f
End Sub
```

Comment: I don´t know VBA, but is there a way to check `b` for a numeric value instead of comparing the first character?

Comment: @Titus There is a numeric check, and the equivalent here would be: `If Not IsNumeric(b) Then`, but that takes more characters. Now, I didn't go in and re-examine all the code; there may be a slightly better way to do this with `IsNumeric` overall. -- Correction, there is a slight improvement here. Thanks!

Comment: I found another four bytes: `For d=9To 1Step-1` and `Fact(d)` --> `For d=0To 8` and `Fact(9-d)` and another two if you do `For d=2To e` and `Fact(e-d+1)*Mid(b,d,1)`

Comment: Can the type cast to Int be written in another way?

Comment: @Titus Look at you, running circles around me. :) I'm tweaking now... As for Int(), I don't think there is a simpler(smaller) method, no.

Comment: I thought about an implicit type cast like the `|0` in PHP and JS; looked it up and that is clearly no option in VB. But there could be two more white spaces to drop. Done running. ;)

Answer (score 0):

## D (159 chars)

```
int x(string n){import std.conv;int r,i=9,f=9*'鶀',d;if(n[0]<48){while(r.text.x<n[1..$].to!int)r++;}else{d=n.to!int;while(i){r=r*10+d/f;d%=f;f/=i--;}}return r;}
```

### Ungolfed and with program entry point

All command line arguments are printed as `<original> -> <converted>`. Only decimal to factoradic is actually implemented in `x`. The other way round just calls `x` with all decimal numbers (0..*) until the result equals the input. This takes ~3 seconds for the largest input (!987654321).

Executable online version: http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/46e425f9

```
void main(string[] args) {
    import std.stdio;
    foreach (arg; args[1 .. $]) {
        writefln("%s -> %s", arg, x(arg));
    }
}

int x(string n) {
    import std.conv;
    int r, i=9, f=9*'鶀', d;  // 鶀's Unicode index equals 8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1

    // If the first character value is less than 48 ('0') it should be a '!'.
    if (n[0] < 48) {
        // Call x with different input (0..*) until it matches our n.
        // r.text.x is rewritten as x(text(r)).
        while (r.text.x < n[1..$].to!int) r++;
    } else {
        d = n.to!int;
        // Try d / 9!, d / 8!, etc. just as in the problem description.
        while (i) {
            r = r*10 + d/f;
            d %= f;
            f /= i--;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: I think it might be possible to change `string n` to `char[]n` to save one byte (I know I'm late here).

Comment: Also, I think `if(n[0]<48){while(r.text.x<n[1..$].to!int)r++;}` can become `if(n[0]<48)while(r.text.x<n[1..$].to!int)r++;` to save two bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 124 bytes

```php
for($f=1;("$">$a=$argn)&&~$c=strrev($a)[$n];)$r+=$c*$f*=++$n;for(;$a>=$f*=++$i;);for(;~-$i;$a%=$f)$r.=0|$a/$f/=$i--;echo+$r;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYtBDoIwFET33sJmJJSmAuvvx4MYFz8NtWxKU40rw61dV1RmNXkzL4VUTucU0g6Sb5HVvt/SKSp@zjU891QrqAHCv5OuqgWO74@cx2cN0RfEK2lkw3ANfMPGINJXJsjAG5lI/9li1w45rMMqHbl7QVr4ljFZS6MLs0GmUt5xtk5cGD8)

Extended

```php
for($f=1;("$">$a=$argn)&&~$c=strrev($a)[$n];) # runs in case of "!" at the beginning
  $r+=$c*$f*=++$n; #reverse string multiply with the next factorial "!"*$f=0
for(;$a>=$f*=++$i;); # runs not in case of "!" at the beginning string comparing. search the factorial that is higher as input value
for(;~-$i;$a%=$f) # runs only when the second loop had runs
  $r.=0|$a/$f/=$i--; # concat the value of the division with the highest factorial used
echo+$r; # Output result
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 150 bytes

```
{/^\!/??([+] [Z*] .comb.skip.reverse,[\*] 1..*)!!(reduce
->\a,\b{a[0]~a[1] div b,a[1]%b},("",+$_),|(first
*[*-1]>$_,[\,] [\*] 1..*).reverse[1..*])[0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 36 chars, 72 bytes

```
{⍵⊆⎕D:10⊥(9..2)⊤⍎⍵⋄t+.×⌽!⍳≢t←⍎¨,1↓⍵}
```

it seems that 10⊥(9..2)⊤ is better than the recursive function, thanks to Howard for the other APL solution that show that... (even if i not understand 100%). Input for numbers without '!' <10!. Test:

```
  u←{⍵⊆⎕D:10⊥(9..2)⊤⍎⍵⋄t+.×⌽!⍳≢t←⍎¨,1↓⍵}    
  u¨'1234' '746' '!54321' '!30311' '!24201'    
141120 101010 719 381 349 
  u '0'
0
  u '!0'
0
  u '9'
111
  u '!111'
9
  u '!9'
9
```