# Convert to and from the backwards-factorial number base

Tags: code-golf, number

I wanted to ask this question: [Convert to and from the factorial number system](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11735/convert-to-and-from-the-factorial-number-system) but I'm a couple of years too late!

So, instead you must convert to and from the <s>lairotcaf</s> backwards-factorial number base! The way it works is that the first digit is always `0`, the maximum value of the next digit is `1`, then `2` and so on. If a number has *n* digits, then each place value is given by *n*!/*i*! where *i* is the digit position starting at `1` on the **left**. The highest digit position is on the **right**. This means that each length uses different place values!

There is a unique shortest way to represent each number, which is what you must output for a decimal number input. If an input number starts with a `0`, convert it to decimal. If it starts with any other digit, convert it to the backwards-factorial number base.

`0` is both valid and the same number in both bases. In the test data no input value will use, or produce a number with a digit higher than `9`. Note that the shortest representation of some numbers starts with multiple `0`s.

```
Digit position:   1   2   3   4   5   6
Place value:    720 360 120  30   6   1
                  0   0   2   2   3   3
                  0   0 240+ 60+ 18+  3=321
```

This is the shortest way to represent `321` because removing a digit makes the highest number possible only `119` (5! - 1).

Test data:

```
Input:      Output:
0           0
1           01
002         2
3           010
011         4
5           012
0012        6
21          0121
0130        24
01000       60
01234       119
001000      120
321         002233
011235      563
0010330     987
4321        0120252
54321       000325536
654321      0010135621
0112351713  2838883
7654321     00102603574
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the fewest bytes wins!

Answer (score 1):

### ES6, <s>135</s> 108 bytes

```
s=>s<"1"?[...s].reduce((t,d,i)=>+d+t*++i):eval("for(i=j=k=1;i<=s;i*=++j);for(r='';k<=j;k++)r+=s%i/(i/=k)|0")
```

Converting from backwards-factorial is nice and easy. Converting to it... not so nice. I found a 119-byte version that doesn't use `eval`:

```
s=>s<"1"?[...s].reduce((t,d,i)=>+d+t*++i):(i=j=k=1,g=_=>s<i||g(i*=++j),g(),[...Array(j)].map(_=>s%i/(i/=k++)|0).join``)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 71 bytes

```perl6
{{/^0/??.comb.reduce(* *-+^++$+*)!![R~] .polymod(+.polymod(1..*)...2)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYrLbsIwEEX3fMVFIEhiMDM2j00Lm27YwrIqVUgcqSrBKI9FxOPXUzuRurlz59xzM8Vl3eYNJhne2/t9caLFbicTm59lYdI6MUGEaC5OQoxFFA6Hn4fXF@TNXprcpoH4byxlFEopVfh8tiN82Ou0Ql0a7K/VsSqQ2QKEs0liD22GQ/xbpxY/ZVkbjBQxDcq4QRaMv8PenuHxxiBS0CBmrFxnBeUYa3JB5FPppR/8o7vNkU4l7aylZ6su1/3pBd6wxqZH2/YP)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 36 bytes

```
⁵R!>³¬TUŻ‘PƤµ³%Ḋ:ṖUŻṾ€
Jṙ1PÐƤḋV€µÇ¬?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVAAr/9qZWxsef//4oG1UiE@wrPCrFRVxbvigJhQxqTCtcKzJeG4ijrhuZZVxbvhub7igqwKSuG5mTFQw5DGpOG4i1bigqzCtcOHwqw/////NDMyMQ)

#### How it works

```
⁵R!>³¬TUŻ‘PƤµ³%Ḋ:ṖUŻṾ€  Aux. link (monad). Integer -> string
⁵R!           [1..10]!
   >³¬T       All indices of above <= input
       UŻ‘    Reverse, prepend 0, increment
          PƤ  Product of each prefix
            µ           Re-focus on the above
             ³%Ḋ:Ṗ      Input % (next base value) // (own base value)
                  UŻṾ€  Reverse, prepend zero, map each digit to string

Jṙ1PÐƤḋV€µÇ¬?  Main link (monad). String -> integer || Integer -> string
         µÇ¬?  If input is string, apply the link on the left;
               otherwise, apply the aux. link
Jṙ1        List of indices rotated once to the left
   PÐƤ     Product of each suffix
      ḋV€  Convert each input char to digit, and dot product with above
```

Uses some tricks from [my own Jelly answer for factorial base challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175834/78410).